# Сервер Linux не принимает запросы по портам

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, сокет

Пытаюсь протестировать работу сокетов на сервере. Если оба сокета (сервер и клиент) запустить на сервере на локалхосте, то все работает. Но если мне нужно клиентский запустить с компьютера, тут начинаются проблемы.

Это серверный:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print ('connected:', addr)

while True:

data = conn.recv(1024)

    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

Это клиентский:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
sock.send(b'hello, world!')
data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()
print (data)
```

IP указываю серверный разве что. Подключение не идет, скрипты работают. Предполагаю что проблема в сервере. Куда копать и в чем проблема? 
Порт разрешен в брандмауэре.

UPD: так как я использую сервер гугла, оказалось что нужно открыть порты через настройки сервиса, а не на самом сервере через ufw. Вопрос решен

Comment: IP-адрес сервера внешний хоть? Маршрут до него есть, NAT отсутствует? Пинги идут?

Comment: IP внешний, пинги идут, что такое NAT не знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как я использую сервер гугла, оказалось что нужно открыть порты через настройки сервиса, а не на самом сервере через ufw. Вопрос решен